# Не работающий Laravel class

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование, классы, controller

Действую согласно [Laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjS2eaqfL5U&list=PLd2_Os8Cj3t8pnG4ubQemoqnTwf0VFEtU&index=4) c 8:00-10:00. В файле `grocerystore\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` строка

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

вообще отсутствовала (не было даже в закомментированном состоянии). Добавил эту строку в вышеуказанный файл, но в результате все равно получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу код файлов

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/my-page', 'MyPlaceController@index');

Route::get('/my-location', function () {
    return 'my city is Krasnodar';
}
);

Route::get('/my-food', function () {
    return 'my favorite food is pizza';
});

Route::get('/my-fruit', function (){
    return 'my favorite fruit is peach';
});

Route::get('/my-shoes', function (){
    return 'my favorite shoes is Piere Carden';
});

Route::get('/my-perfume', function () {
    return 'my favorite perfume is Lacoste';
});

Route::get('/my-device', function () {
    return 'I use Asus device';
});

Route::get('/my-drink', function () {
    return 'I drink Coca-Cola';
});

Route::get('/my-country', function () {
    return 'I live in Russia';
});
```

Подскажите как устранить ошибку.

Comment: Ну написано же: "нет класса MyPlaceController". Вы его метод добавляете как обработчик маршрута my-page `Route::get('/my-page', 'MyPlaceController@index');`.

Comment: Вообще не рекомендую вам смотреть видосы по ларавель. Откройте их [доку](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing), изучайте, ???, PROFIT!

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было использовать команду

```
Route::get('/my-page', 'App\Http\Controllers\MyPlaceController@index');
```

вместо

```
Route::get('/my-page', 'MyPlaceController@index');
```

Comment: Либо импортировать его в начале файла `use App\Http\Controllers\MyPlaceController;`